# Identify 4 pin DC power supply connector

Tags: power-supply, connector

Can you please identify this 4 pin DC power supply connector:
[image]

Comment: Probabčy industrial M12 A coded connector

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an an GX-12 connector.
Used in the aero-industry.

Comment: What's the difference between M12 and GX12?